# JavaScript Thumbnails From Array

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to work on a website currently that displays pictures with the help of java-script. The way that I have this website set up at the moment, an image is displayed above numbered photo links. Instead of having numbers listed below the pictures, I'd like to have the numbers be thumbnails of the pictures. Is it possible to replace them with images? Any help is appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```js
var photos = new Array();
var photoindex = 0;

photos[0] = "images/piano.jpg";
photos[1] = "images/guitar.jpg";
photos[2] = "images/studio.jpg";
photos[3] = "images/sheetmusic.jpg";

function backward() {
  if (photoindex > 0) {
    document.images.p.src = photos[--photoindex];
  }
}

function forward() {
  if (photoindex < photos.length - 1) {
    document.images.p.src = photos[++photoindex];
  }
}

for (i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
  document.write("<a href=\"javascript: goto(" + i + ");\">" + i + "</a> ");
}

function goto(n) {
  if (n < photos.length && n >= 0) {
    photoindex = n;
    document.images.p.src = photos[photoindex];
  }
}
```

```html
<br>
<div style="text-align:center;left:5px;">
  <table width="250" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="3" align="center" valign="top">
        <img src="images/weloveweb.png" name="p" width="250" height="188" id="p" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td valign="top"><a href="javascript: backward();">&lt;&lt;</a>
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: center">
      </td>
      <td valign="top" style="text-align: right"><a href="javascript: forward();">&gt;&gt;</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: So add an image tag....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your thumbnail urls are stored in the `photos` array, what you need to do to display a thumbnail instead of its index is to create an `img` tag with a `src` attribute containing each thumbnail's url (i.e. `photos[i]`).

Change:

```
for (i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
  document.write("<a href=\"javascript: goto(" + i + ");\">" + i + "</a> ");
// ------------------------------------------------------------^ change this `i`
}
```

Into:

```
for (i = 0; i < photos.length; i++) {
  document.write("<a href=\"javascript: goto(" + i + ");\">" + "<img src=" + photos[i] + "/></a> ");
}
```

Comment: The problem is, when I do this, it shows a text link, not a thumbnail.

Comment: Thank you, this mostly worked! However, now, instead of showing the image thumbnail, the thumbnail shows as broken (even though clicking them does bring up the correct image). Any idea's on what went wrong here?

Comment: You might need a relative path for your thumbnails so prepend a `./` before each url, like `./images/imagename`